# Is Bluetooth DUN profile supported on Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, connection

Is Bluetooth DUN profile supported on Android?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DUN isn't part of the stock Android.  But it is supported on Android via 3rd party apps, such as [BlueDUN](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blue_dun&hl=en)